# how to print last element after deleting odd indices continuously

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I am trying to delete the odd positions starting from 1 continuously and to get the last remaining element;

e.g.:
n=6;

1 2 3 4 5 6

first: removing odd indices will get (2 4 6);

second: removing odd indices will get (4) which is the answer...

here is my code:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Odd_Deletions {

    public static void oddDeletions(HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm) {
        int j = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < hm.size(); i++) {

            if (hm.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
                continue;
            } else {
                hm.put(j, i);
                j++;

            }

        }
        //System.out.println(hm);
        while (true) {
            if (hm.size() == 1) {
                System.out.println(hm);
                break;
            } else
                oddDeletions(hm);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 6;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            hm.put(i, i);
        }
        //System.out.println(hm);
        oddDeletions(hm);
    }
}
```

why I am getting StackOverflow Error and what is wrong with this logic?

can anyone fix it?

Thanks and regards;

Comment: dry run `oddDeletions` method. You have a recursion but when does it stop?

Comment: You never remove anything from `hm`.

Comment: Perhaps the `HashMap` is not the right class to use here

Comment: The answer will always be the largest index in the form `2^n` for some positive integer n, so the answer can be calculated in constant time if you know the size of your input.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the `HashMap` is not the right class to use here. Anyway, as @Welbog pointed out, you never remove anything from your table. Also, why use recursion?

Try something like this:

```
    while (hm.size() > 1) {
        int j = 1;
        int last = hm.size();
        for (int i = 1; i <= last; i++) {
            int value = hm.remove(i);
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                hm.put(j, value);
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible solutions.

(1) I don't know why you need to apply that "removal process" on the `HashMap` with that logic, anyway a possible solution could be the following one. But use it only if you need to apply to a `Map` where you need to remove its entries by, for some reasons, applying that logic on the Map keys.

```
public class RemovingOddIndexes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // initialize
        int n = 6;
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            hm.put(i, i);
        }

        //
        oddDeletions(hm);

        // print result
        hm.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(String.format("%s:%s, ", k, v)));
    }

    public static void oddDeletions(HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm) {

        while (hm.size() > 1) {
            hm.keySet()
              .stream()
              .sorted()
              .forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {
                  int i = 1;

                  @Override
                  public void accept(Integer n) {

                      if (i % 2 == 1)
                          hm.remove(n);
                      ++i;
                  }
              });
        }
    }
}
```

(2) Otherwise use a simple `LinkedList` that you can skim recursively. I prefer to use a `LinkedList` over an `ArrayList` because the alg need to remove elements at every iteration, till the last one. And the remove operation on a `LinkedList` performs better.

```
public class RemovingOddIndexes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // initialize
        int n = 6;
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }

        //
        oddDeletions(list);

        // print result
        list.forEach(i -> System.out.println(String.format("%s, ", i)));
    }

    public static void oddDeletions(List<Integer> list) {

        while (list.size() > 1) {
            int i = 1;
            Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                it.next();
                if (i++ % 2 == 1) {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(3) Last option, the fastest way possible

```
int lastOdd = 1 << (int)(Math.log(n) / Math.log(2))
```